# Oracle 11g SQL case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I'm trying to modify a where clause in a query as it's creating a Cartesian join on the country table on an Oracle report. The problem line is below. The report variable :P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR can be NULL, '052' or '044', If :P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is NULL then I want to do search for both member.d_tax_country_id,member.d_mcps_tax_country_id against country_id on country table.

I was thinking of a case statement in the where clause but I've come stuck.

```
 AND country.country_id = 
 decode(:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR, NULL,country.country_id,'052',
        member.d_tax_country_id,member.d_mcps_tax_country_id)
```

Any ideas on what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   AND ((:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR = '052' and country.country_id = member.d_tax_country_id)
     OR (:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR = '044' and country.country_id = member.d_mcps_tax_country_id)
     OR (:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is null and (country.country_id = member.d_tax_country_id OR country.country_id = member.d_mcps_tax_country_id)))
```

Comment: Hi Vercelli, if P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is NULL then I don't want to be joining back to the country.country_id i want to do a IN  (member.d_tax_country_id,member.d_mcps_tax_country_id) to get both records if they exist

Comment: @ShaunKinnair post full query please

Comment: @ShaunKinnair I changed it. No `NVL2` just `AND/OR/IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not very clear. What should happen if `:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR` is **not** NULL? From your description in words, it seems you don't need any further condition to be checked in that case. If so use:

```
AND (:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is not NULL 
     or country.country_id = member.d_tax_country_id
     or country.country_id = member.d_mcps_tax_country_id  -- or perhaps "and", not "or"??
    )
```

If this isn't what you meant, please clarify the plain-English description of your requirement (clearly a query that is NOT doing what you want will not help much).

Comment: Hi mathguy, If p_payment_soc_nbr is NULL then I want to search for both member.d_tax_country_id and member.d_mcps_tax_country_id against the country.country_id. So basically I'm doing an IN statement (i.e. IF :P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is NULL AND country.country_id IN (member.d_tax_country_id,member.d_mcps_tax_country_id)

Comment: OK. What if `:P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR` is **not** NULL? What I show in my Answer will do the following: IF :P_PAYMENT_SOC_NBR is **not** NULL, then it doesn't check for any additional conditions. However, if it IS NULL, then it checks to see if `country.country_id` equals one or the other of the country id's from the `member` table; exactly what you requested.